# Flex inbuilt Settings menu event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have a browser based flex application and i use the floating iframe method to show a google map.
At various points in the GUI i need to hide the iframe and then show it again once the map tab has been chosen.

I have a problem with the inbuilt flash menu seen below:
[image: Context Menu]

If the user selects settings it opens the menu as a modal making the gui unuseable and the setting menu is actually hidden behind the iframe.

I need to be able to detect when this menu is opened so i can hide the iframe, either with an event listener on the menu itself or on modal activation or whatever? Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want the menu to appear then try hiding it like this http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/right-click-and-custom-context-menu-in-flash-flex/.

Comment: @Gowtham - i did something similar `$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
});`